# asm/errno.h: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, gcc, make, g++

I'm trying to install gcc 4.8.1 at the moment. Currently 4.8.2 and 4.9.1 are installed. I downloaded an 4.8.1 from here http://gcc.cybermirror.org/releases/gcc-4.8.1/ . After extracting the files I did a `./configure` and then tried `make`. At the end of `make`, I get this error

```
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/errno.h>
```

I am new to linux so I do not know how to find or add this header file.

Edit: Steps I made:

1. Extract gcc-4.8.1.tar.gz to a folder
2. Open terminal window
3. `cd gcc-4.8.1`
4. `./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu`
5. `make -j4`

I don't know what I did differently but it finally compiled. After that I did make install. My question now how do I use this instead of 4.8.2 which using the command    gcc-4.8
still defaults to.

Comment: Please tell me you did not do `sudo make install`. It's highly recommended when building stuff from source that you use `--prefix` flag (and with GCC, the `--program-suffix` flag) while configuring. Since you haven't, try running `/usr/bin/gcc`.

Comment: @muru Thank you so much for your help! I have managed to use 4.8.1 now. I didn't realize I needed to purge 4.8.2 first. Also, I did use sudo make install. Is there a reason not to?

Comment: Well, you configured GCC without giving a suffix. So while `/usr/bin/gcc` should normally be handled by Ubuntu's package system, it has now been overwritten by the one you compiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `asm/errno.h` header is provided by [a variety of packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=asm%2Ferrno.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=amd64). Odd that `gcc` would require it, but you can try:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev
```

You also need to tell GCC to look for an architecture and OS specific location for the headers:

```
../configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu
```

(or `i386-linux-gnu` for 32-bit Ubuntu).

---

It's highly recommended when building stuff from source that you use `--prefix` flag (and with GCC, the `--program-suffix` flag) while configuring. Since you haven't, try running `/usr/bin/gcc`.

Thus:

```
tar xf gcc-4.8.1.tar.gz 
mkdir gcc
cd gcc
../gcc-4.8.1/configure  --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local --program-suffix=-4.8.1
make -j
sudo make install
```

Now your GCC binaries will be installed to `/usr/local/bin/`, and other things in other folders in `/usr/local`.

For example:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8.1  # or simply gcc-4.8.1, since this folder is in your PATH
```

Note how I'm running `configure` and `make` from a different directory, outside of where the GCC source is? That's how [the GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) recommend that GCC be built.

Comment: Hi I just tried installing that but it said it was already installed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to specify those. Could you give me an example of how I would go about doing that?

Comment: Do you have linux-headers installed?

Comment: muru, I tried that but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @muru, Yeah I did use make clean. I also tried deleting the folder, reextracting the files and repeating the steps. No success.

Comment: @muru, uname -m gives x86_64. I have the folder but no errno.h inside it

Comment: @muru I edited the post. I successfully compiled it. How do I use it now?

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error on `ubuntu-xenial 4.4.0-75-generic`.

I found I had a `/usr/include/asm-generic` folder, but no `/usr/include/asm`, which gcc was looking for.

Creating a symlink solved it for me.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/asm-generic/ /usr/include/asm
```

**Fair warning**: Although, sometimes, one has to do this kind of trickery, it's not always a good idea just because it works. I'm doing this in a virtual machine, which I can recreate by running a simple script, and that is why it's no big deal if I break something.

Comment: This symlink worked for me.  Though I wish the maintainers of this stuff would just fix it.  It's been broken for about 7 years now.