# What package provides asm/errno.h for x32 ABI?

Tags: compiling, gcc

I'm trying to compile strace 4.19 on 64-bit Kubuntu 14.04, and the compilation fails with the following error:

```
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory
```

I was able to reproduce the problem to that of compilation of the test C source:

```
#include <errno.h>
```

It compiles fine with `-m32` and `-m64` GCC options, but fails with the error mentioned above for `-mx32`:

```
$ gcc -c -x c -mx32 - <<< '#include <errno.h>'
In file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
                 from <stdin>:1:
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I assume I'm missing some package which does provide `asm/errno.h` for x32 ABI. What is this package?

[Another question](https://askubuntu.com/q/530248/113421) I viewed doesn't solve this:  I've tried what the accepted answer suggested, and it didn't change anything at all. Besides, it isn't even applicable to pure GCC without any autotools build. And the other answer is just a dirty hack, which I don't know how will break the strace build. Also, that other question doesn't mention x32, which is the core of this question.

Comment: It's referenced and included by lots of packages, but I think the one that you probably want is `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: @CharlesGreen it's already the newest version. Please note that `-m32` and `-m64` compile successfully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asm/errno.h: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530248/asm-errno-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @CharlesGreen no it's not: I've tried what the accepted answer suggested, and it didn't change anything at all. Besides, it isn't even applicable to pure GCC without any autotools build. And the other answer is just a dirty hack, which I don't know how will break the strace build.

Comment: Maybe `linux-libc-dev:i386` and or `libc6-dev:i386` (later will install former, former is most likely..

Comment: @doug I have them installed, but this doesn't matter: x32 isn't i386, it's a variation of amd64.

Comment: I'll withdraw my duplicate vote - are you running on an x32 system, or cross compiling for something?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I'm running on a x86_64 system, compiling `strace` for it without any special `configure` settings. Actually even `gcc -c -x c -mx32 - <<< '#include <asm/errno.h>'` command causes this error.

Comment: Try installing `gcc-multilib`

Comment: @doug that's **the** solution. Funnily enough, all this package contains is a symlink`/usr/include/asm -> x86_64-linux-gnu/asm`. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this issue support for the x32 ABI in gcc must be enabled.

The gcc-multilib package will provide that via a /usr/include/linux/asm symlink. For reference this was seen in a debian bug where the above info was provided. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=871946